# Form send button php not working

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple form:

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="NAME:" size="100" class="grey-bg"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="E-MAIL:" size="100" class="grey-bg"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="20" cols="201" placeholder="MESSAGE:" size="162"></textarea>
    <br />
    <div>
        <input id="contact-send-btn" type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the php file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "xxxxxxxx";

    $email_subject = "Hello";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['message']) ||

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($message) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

However when I click the button it just opens the php file in the browser and nothing is received in my inbox? All I want is to receive the email with the details in the form?

Comment: Open **http://localhost** tell what you see

Comment: That hasn't changed anything?

Comment: You probably don't have PHP Apache installed in your system thats why you are seeing the content of the .php file

Comment: From Where `$email_from` coming ??

Comment: Everything inside this `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {...}` will NOT happen and error reporting would have thrown you something about an undefined index email notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly Or just remove it actually, since they're not handling files.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems.

## Encoding Type

> ```
> enctype="text/plain"
> ```

PHP does not support plain text encoded form data. **Remove that attribute** (and use the default encoding type).

See also [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#plain-text-form-data):

> Payloads using the text/plain format are intended to be human readable. They are **not reliably interpretable by computer**, as the format is ambiguous (for example, there is no way to distinguish a literal newline in a value from the newline at the end of the value).

## Test for submission

You said `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {`

… but you don't have any field with `name="email"`. Test to see if a field you actually have exists*

## Opening PHP in the browser

This statement is a little ambiguous:

> it just opens the php file in the browser

If you mean that your browser displays the PHP source code, then see this question: [PHP code is not being executed (I can see it on source code of page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

## Asides

> `placeholder="NAME:"`

[The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

> ```
>  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
> ```

This fails to match many perfectly valid email addresses (such as those with a `+` in the section before the `@` or those from the `.museum` top level domain).

Comment: Exactly and just as I told the OP [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435124/form-send-button-php-not-working#comment56616804_34435124) I left them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You did not add `name` attribute to submit button.

Change

```
<input id="contact-send-btn" type="submit" value="Send">
```

To:

```
<input id="contact-send-btn" type="submit" value="Send" name="email"/>
```

While posting forms, only elements with name `get` posted.

In your case, submit button has no name attribute, so, it was not getting posted.

Hence, it is not coming into the `if`.

Comment: I did that but still nothing?

Comment: I believe their use of "email" was intended for `<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="E-MAIL:" size="100" class="grey-bg"/>` and should be adding another input for "email" and changing their placeholder and not as the submit button. Their first conditional statement is where it's all supposed to "happen" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have apache , php installed thats why you are seeing the content of the .php file . If you are on Windows Install XAMPP if you are on Linux [Install LAMP Stack](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu)  . Hope this helps